# What itemtype to use for a rentals vacancies website?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I am French, and I am developing a rental vacancies website. I would like add microdata on the rental vacancy offers (house, villa, appartment...), but I don't know which itemtype to use. Offer, Product, or an other?

http://schema.org/Offer

http://schema.org/Product

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a SEO question more suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several relevant schemas that apply, and you will be best off using a combination of them to represent your Offers.  The **Offer** should be your root element, because it represents something that ican be purchased for a price.  The **itemOffered** property has the **Product** type, so it is the logical extension point for embedding product content.  Think of the Offer as your sales pitch and the Product as what you are actually selling. There is a metadata schema for [Residences](http://schema.org/Residence) which include information about the domain of your Products.  You could combine this with the Product itemscope or nest it within the Product (possibly via the **model** property).

Metadata from the [GoodRelations schema](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1) can be used to extend schema.org's limited Product vocabulary as well.

I also see an opportunity for leveraging the Review schema (for any reviews in the corresponding Product property), and potentially [TouristAttraction](http://schema.org/TouristAttraction), if the rental's proximity to tourist attraction is a selling point.  I also noticed that there is a **LodgingBusiness** schema that inherits from **Organization**.  This should be used to encapsulate content about your actual client (or whoever rents out the apartments/villas to renters).

Answer (score 0):

Use the new version of schema.org (0.99) with the following properties for the **http://schema.org/Offer**:

- **businessFunction**; use http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#LeaseOut as the value.
- **eligibleDuration**: The duration for which the given offer is valid.
- **availabilityStarts**: The beginning of the availability of the rental object.
- **availabilityEnds**: The end of the availability of the rental object

If you need detailed patterns, please contact me via http://www.heppresearch.com/contact. We built the new e-commerce module for schema.org.