# Renting, Booking and Schema.org

Tags: semantic-web, microdata, schema.org

Is there any way to express the idea of time (as in day or weeks) for a booking or a rental using [Schema.org](http://Schema.org) or/and GoodRelation?

It could be the combination of a product and an offer, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058170/what-itemtype-to-use-for-a-rentals-vacancies-website), but it doesn't really express the idea of the same product being available at different times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the new version of schema.org (0.99) with the itemtype **http://schema.org/Offer**. Make clear that you have a rental offer using the property
 - **businessFunction** with http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#LeaseOut as the value.

The validity of the offer is specified using the properties **validFrom** and **validThrough** (i.e. the period of time during which one can accept your offer).

For multiple alternative rental periods, create multiple offer entities.

The availability period and the minimum / maximum duration of a stay is specified using

- **eligibleDuration**: The duration for which the given offer is valid.
- **availabilityStarts**: The beginning of the availability of the rental object.
- **availabilityEnds**: The end of the availability of the rental object

The UN/CEFACT unit code for days is DAY, for months it is MON.

The billing increment etc. is modeled using http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification.

If you need detailed patterns, please contact me via http://www.heppresearch.com/contact. We built the new e-commerce module for schema.org.